# Django Aggregation: How I can get Max value only?

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-aggregation, django-2.2

First of all, I'm using Django 2.2 and Python 3.7

I have this in my models.py

```
class Test(models.Model):
    session = models.IntegerField()
    x_pos = models.IntegerField()
    y_pos = models.IntegerField()
```

What am trying to do is to get the max value of 'session' from my database.

In my views.py I succesfully get the max value by this:

```
from .models import Test
from django.db.models import Max

max_session = Test.objects.all().aggregate(Max('session'))
print(max_session)
```

The problem is when I print the result i get `{'session__max': 35}`

How can I get the value 35 only, in my max_session variable?

Comment: try print(max_session['session_max'])

Comment: @julien unfortunately that gives me an error:
 print(max_session['session_max'])
**KeyError: 'session_max'**

Comment: could you provide exactly the output of `print(max_session)` ? From what you provided the output is a dictionnary with 'session_max' key, so you should not have a KeyError

Comment: Ah I forgot an underscore, try `print(max_session['session__max'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
print(max_session['session__max'])
```

Comment: Thanks @julien for your answer!  Just a warning, it has a double underscore!